# Cisco ASA Static NAT with SLA tracking

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, nat, dnat

I don't believe this is possible iwth the Cisco ASA series, but figured I would as the community.

If I have an Cisco ASA, can I use the sla feature to track a NAT statement? for example. objReal1=10.1.1.1

```
sla monitor 1
type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho 10.1.1.1 interface inside
num-packets 3
timeout 1000
frequency 10

track 1 rtr 1 reachability

nat (inside,outside) source static objSrc objSrc destination static objNAT objReal1 track 1
nat (inside,outside) source static objSrc objSrc destination static objNAT objReal2
```

Reasoning is we have some Servers that are local, but if they fail the SLA ping, I want to translate to something else that isn't local.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the **sla monitoring** feature only applies to static routes, not NAT.